# Sticky footer doesn't have 100% width

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I have a website with the following structure:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div id="anyContent"></div>
    <div id="pagecontent">
        <div id="bigContent"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`bigContent` is dynamic and often stretches to large sizes (demonstrated by its width and height). Because a lot of elements are dynamically rendered into the div, `bigContent` isn't set to a static width.

How can I force the footer to have the same width as `bigContent`?
See my example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47hb3fcn/).

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

#page {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#bigContent {
    background: black;
    height: 3000px;
    width: 5000px;
}

#footer {
    background: blue;
    clear: left;
    bottom: 0px;   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Looks 100% to me in your Fiddle - Chrome 64bit W7

Comment: check my answer is that what you are after? @maniac

Comment: Since you set inline style to div#bigContent width=5000px; you can set for the footer width=5000px will fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some properties to `#pagecontent` then it will work as per your need:

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
#pagecontent {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#pagecontainer {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}       
#bigContent {
    background: black;
}
#footer {
    background: blue;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagecontainer">
    <div id="anyContent"> </div>
    <div id="pagecontent">
        <div id="bigContent" style="width:500px; height:150px;"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the width: 5000px and height to 3000px.

```
<div id="bigContent" style="width:5000px; height:3000px;"></div>
```

Try this

```
<div id="bigContent"></div>
```

and add

```
#bigContent {
    background: yellow;
    height: 1000px;  
    width: 100%;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/47hb3fcn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You set `width` to `#bigContent`, better would be to set this width to `#pagecontent`.

```
<div id="pagecontainer">
    <div id="anyContent"></div>
    <div id="pagecontent" style="width:5000px;">
        <div id="bigContent" style="height:3000px;"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47hb3fcn/3/

Comment: The width of bigContent grows dynamic. There are many dom elements rendered with Javascript/Jquery into this div. That's why it's not possible for me to set the width of pageContent accordingly.