# how to position panel at bottom of page

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a div containing 3 panels all with width of 100% of div (div is 100% width of page). One at the top, one in middle will hold dynamic controls and one at bottom.

I want the panel at the bottom to remain there no matter if the middle is empty or not. How can i do this in c#, asp.net or html?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidLastValidateImgBtnEventId" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidLastExpandImgBtnEventId" runat="server" />   
        </div>
        <div id="divMaster" align="center" style="height: 100%">
            <asp:Panel ID="PnlNav" runat="server" Width="75%" Height="25%">
                <asp:Image ID="imgNav1" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/img/nav/nav_preserve_target_active_logo.png" Width="24%" 
                    Margin-left="-10px" BorderStyle="None"/>
                <asp:Image ID="imgNav2" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/img/nav/nav_preserve_analyse_inactive_logo.png" Width="24%" 
                    Margin-left="-10px"/>
                <asp:Image ID="imgNav3" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/img/nav/nav_preserve_metadata_inactive_logo.png" Width="24%" 
                    Margin-left="-10px"/>
                <asp:Image ID="imgNav4" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/img/nav/nav_preserve_preserve_inactive_logo.png" Width="24%" 
                    Margin-left="-10px" BorderStyle="None" />
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="PnlButtons" runat="server" Width="75%" Height="25%">
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="PnlFooter" runat="server" Width="75%" Height="25%">
            <asp:Image ID="imgFooter1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/footer/fp7_logo.png" 
                Width="32%" />
            <asp:Image ID="imgFooter2" runat="server" 
                ImageUrl="~/img/footer/app_logo.png" Width="32%" />
            <asp:Image ID="imgFooter3" runat="server" 
                ImageUrl="~/img/footer/developedby_logo.PNG" Width="32%" />
        </asp:Panel>           
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using css only

for your reference check this

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

[Sticky footer doesn't have 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037864/sticky-footer-doesnt-have-100-width/27038498#27038498)

Comment: I wasnt planning on setting the height in pxls but this will have to do although i cant believe this is not possible, such a simple and seemingly common req!

Comment: does anybody know how to do it with % height = 25%

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Fearghal</title>
    <link href="Fearghal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidLastValidateImgBtnEventId" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidLastExpandImgBtnEventId" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div id="divMaster" align="center" style="height: 100%">
        <asp:Panel ID="PnlNav" runat="server" Width="75%" Height="25%">
            <asp:Image ID="imgNav1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/nav/nav_preserve_target_active_logo.png"
                Width="24%" Margin-left="-10px" BorderStyle="None" />
            <asp:Image ID="imgNav2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/nav/nav_preserve_analyse_inactive_logo.png"
                Width="24%" Margin-left="-10px" />
            <asp:Image ID="imgNav3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/nav/nav_preserve_metadata_inactive_logo.png"
                Width="24%" Margin-left="-10px" />
            <asp:Image ID="imgNav4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/nav/nav_preserve_preserve_inactive_logo.png"
                Width="24%" Margin-left="-10px" BorderStyle="None" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="PnlButtons" runat="server" Width="75%" Height="25%">
        </asp:Panel>
        <div class="customFooter">
            <asp:Panel ID="PnlFooter" runat="server" Width="75%" Height="25%">
                <asp:Image ID="imgFooter1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/footer/fp7_logo.png" Width="32%" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgFooter2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/footer/app_logo.png" Width="32%" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgFooter3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/footer/developedby_logo.PNG"
                    Width="32%" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is CSS :

```
.customFooter
{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

it's works for me,hope it helps

Comment: Thx, i found the fix, i was missing a height style in my body tag, this set the entire body to 100% and everything fell into place then.

Answer (score 0):

My body tag was missing a height style, doh! This meant that all child controls did not make up 100% but just took what they needed.

```
    <div id="divMaster" align="center" style="height:100%">
```